# Return data from async AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda

How do I get the data back from a lambda invoked with as an event to the calling function?

Essentially the lambda function I have is:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var data = {};
    data.foo ='hello';
    callback(null, data)
}
```

and the invoking function looks like this:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
var params = {
    FunctionName: 'SomeFunction',
    InvocationType: 'Event'
};

lambda.invoke(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

However the only thing I get back from the function is

```
{
  "StatusCode": 202,
  "Payload": ""
}
```

I thought the point of the callback parameter was to allow the invoking function to get the data when the function has finished. Am I using it wrong or is what I am asking not possible with Lambdas?

Answer (score 9):

When you invoke the Lambda function you need to set the `InvocationType` to `'RequestResponse'` instead of `'Event'`.

When using the `Event` type your callback is invoked when the payload has been received by AWS's servers. When using the `RequestResponse` type your callback is invoked only after the Lambda function has completed and you will receive the data it provided to its callback. It is not possible to do what you want with the `Event` type.

Comment: Is it not possible to do it with `'Event'` type? I thought the point of the callback parameter was for the invoking function to be able to get the data from the lambda when it finished executing?

Comment: Shame. `You can use the optional callback to return information to the caller, otherwise return value is null`, this made it sound like I could use the callback to return result of the invocation

Comment: @user2127726 I mean, you can… just use the right `InvocationType`. Why is changing that an issue?

Comment: RequestResponse is synchronous right? So there would have to be another thread to prevent blocking the calling one right? Just some people don't seem to like that extra step

Comment: @user2127726 no, using the `RequestResponse` type will not make the call synchronous.

Comment: would you be able to provide a source? [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html) seems to say otherwise

Comment: @user2127726 try switching the `InvotcationType` to `RequestResponse` and simply adding two `console.log(new Date())` statements to your code. One just after the call to `lambda.invoke` and another inside its callback. If it was synchronous you would see the same approximate date, but instead you will see a significant difference (hundreds of milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

As @MatthewPope commented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58176765/599072) answer, if you do need the results from an asynchronous Lambda execution, you should consider having the Lambda function write its results to S3 (or something to that effect) at a known location where clients of the Lambda function can periodically check for the existence of the result.