# Getting the response results from an asynchronous call to AWS lambda in python

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS lambda function which I can call synchronously and get results back alright with below code

```
response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName=FUNCTION_NAME,
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        LogType='Tail',
        Payload=payload,
        Qualifier=$LATEST
    )
```

The response Payload is of type `<botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x115fb3160>` So I use below code to extract the payload which works fine.

```
response_body = response['Payload']
response_str = response_body.read().decode('utf-8')
response_dict = eval(response_str)
```

Now, I need to call my lambda asynchronously, so I change the invocation type with `InvocationType='Event'`

It gives me a response with payload of the same type as before, `botocore.response.StreamingBody object` but I am getting error with this line - `response_dict = eval(response_str)`

The error message says

```
    response_dict = eval(response_str)
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

What am I missing? If the response payload is same type as synchronous call, why is this parsing error? Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

For clarity, I understand that if the `InvocationType='Event'`, then we only get the status of the `invoke` call, not the lambda function result. In my case though, I need both - launch the lambda async and get the result back when done. How do I do that? Is writing the result back to s3 and periodically checking that the only option?

Comment: I've answered why this doesn't work as you expected, below, but what I couldn't anticipate was what you were actually trying to accomplish by making the invocation asynchronous, since you still wanted the result returned.  Please advise, and perhaps I or someone else can help you solve the original issue, if one remains.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot please see the edit

Comment: There's no architected way to do what you want in Lambda. You need to design a solution. One option would be for the client invoking the initial Lambda to send a UUID along with its request, then the async Lambda does its work and writes the results somewhere (DynamoDB or S3, for example, using the client-supplied UUID as a key), and the client can then poll a second Lambda passing that same UUID in order to retrieve the results when they become available. Or the original Lambda sends a notification via SNS and your client polls SNS.

Comment: Currently it can be achieved using AWS Step functions: https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/

Answer (score 7):

`InvocationType='Event'` means you aren't getting a response.  An asynchronous Lambda invocation means you just want to invoke the function, not wait for the response.  The response payload from the function is discarded by the service.

> When you invoke a function asynchronously, Lambda sends the event to a queue. A separate process reads events from the queue and runs your function. **When the event is added to the queue, Lambda returns a success response without additional information.** *(emphasis added)*
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html

Note that the *queue* mentioned here is a queue inside the Lambda service, not to be confused with Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS).

Comment: In addition, if you do need the results from an asynchronous Lambda execution, you should consider having the Lambda function write its results to S3 (or something to that effect) at a known location where clients of the Lambda function can periodically check for the existence of the result.

Comment: @MatthewPope It seems like you would need a separate s3 object for each invocation of the worker lambda right? Ideally I could track the state of all the asynchronous invocations in a *single* s3 file, but I'm struggling to see how they could all access the same file without overwriting one another's results. Any ideas?

Comment: @MaileCupo, my point is that if you need the results of an asynchronous invocation, you can write the results to some known location and the requestor can look for them there. I don’t have any particular suggestions for how you would implement your use case. You should consider asking a new question on SO for it.