# Tracking states of asynchronous aws lambda invocations?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a 'master' aws lambda function which calls multiple 'workers'. I am invoking the workers asynchronously, so they do not return any json to the master. Here is some analogous code:

**Master**:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    config = #### LOAD LIST OF THINGS TO DO FROM A CONFIG FILE ON AN S3 BUCET ###
 
    client = boto3.client('lambda',
                        config = Config(retries={'max_attempts': 0}))
                         
    for t in config['tasks']:        
        client.invoke(FunctionName={worker_arn},
                      InvocationType='Event',
                      Payload=json.dumps(config['tasks'][t]))
```

**Worker**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #### DO STUFF ####
    #### DUMP STATE INFO SOMEWHERE (TO AN S3 BUCKET?) ###
```

Since the workers are being invoked by an "Event" rather than a "RequestResponse", they [do not return any json info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58176134/getting-the-response-results-from-an-asynchronous-call-to-aws-lambda-in-python/58176765?noredirect=1#comment115683419_58176765). That linked thread suggests dumping state data to an S3 bucket. However multiple concurrent processes would have trouble editing a single file on an S3 bucket because they would overwrite one anothers' states. What is the best practice for persisting state info for asynchronous lambda calls?

Comment: You seem to be manually creating a workflow. Instead, consider using [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/).

Comment: Would step functions let me concurrently call dozens of worker functions and collect their responses to return any errors from the base lambda? It seems like there is a significant amount of overhead to using step functions.

Comment: Step Functions supports dynamic parallelism. You can use the Map Fan-Out pattern. I wouldn't say there's significant overhead here, especially compared to trying to roll your own orchestration.

Comment: This sounds like the right approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given a shot to [AWS Lambda Destinations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/)? There are 4 types of Destinations supported

1.SQS Queue
2.SNS Topic

3.Event Bridge Event Bus

4.Lambda Function itself.

Event Bridge would be good to integrate here, and then later on the process however you want to from Event Bridge